# html5 date with simple_form setting to nil when partially filled in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have an HTML5 date in my `simple_form` based rails form like so:

```
    = f.input :start_at, include_blank: true, html5: true
```

I have a validation rule that looks like this:

```
  def start_at_in_future
    if start_at.present? && start_at <= DateTime.now
      errors.add(:start_at, 'must be in the future')
    end
  end
```

But when it's only partially filled in like this:

[image: Partially filled in simple form]

It simply marks it as `nil` (which is allowed in my model)

How can I detect "partially filled in html5 dates" and have them validated?

Comment: That validation does not change the value of the attribute. It just adds an error to the errors object. This is something completely different. Can you please provide us with the parameters from the log, the model and the controller? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also what is the type of the rendered input? datetime-local, date or time?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the time field, you can use `as: :date` like so:

```
= f.input :start_at, as: date, html5: true, include_blank: true
```

But as for partially filled out inputs (e.g. day and month but no year selected), I checked what the controller receives and it's just an empty string, so the html input itself is not sending anything if it's only partially filled in.